# MySQL Error: Unknown column 'product_name' in 'where clause' in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am trying to retrieve the product name from order_product table using the below MySQL query:

**Query**

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
       CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, 
       ( SELECT os.name 
         FROM order_status os 
         WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
         AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
       ) AS order_status, 
       ( SELECT name 
         FROM order_product 
         WHERE order_id = o.order_id 
         LIMIT 1 
       ) AS product_name, 
       o.shipping_code, 
       o.total, 
       o.currency_code, 
       o.currency_value, 
       o.date_added, 
       o.date_modified, 
       o.telephone, 
       o.shipping_city, 
       o.order_type, 
       o.shipping_address_1 
FROM   order o 
AND    product_name LIKE '%smart tv3%'`
```

Please help me resolve this error. And also give me a guidelines.

[This is the error, I got it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajZZK.png)

Comment: You don't have an ordered_product in your query did you mean order_product?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes,  order_product table

Comment: You missing a WHERE before your AND

Comment: @wayneOS Actually its not problem on WHERE, I got error  product_name as unknown column

Comment: Try `HAVING product_name LIKE '%smart tv3%'` instead of `AND    product_name LIKE '%smart tv3%'`

Comment: @wayneOS  It also returns the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure that the error is from this query? It says something about `SELECT COUNT(*)` but there is no such thing in your query...

Comment: @wayneOS  yes, i'm sure error is from this query, if im remove this query all are working normal

Comment: Sorry i'm not really sure whats going on. can you please show the whole error-message, not just the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the error by replacing the AND to HAVING in the query. :)

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
   o.order_id,
   CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer,
  (
  SELECT
     os.name 
  FROM
     order_status os 
  WHERE
     os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
     AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
)
 AS order_status,
(
  SELECT
     name 
  FROM
     order_product 
  WHERE
     order_id = o.order_id LIMIT 1 
)
 AS product_name,
 o.shipping_code,
 o.total,
 o.currency_code,
 o.currency_value,
 o.date_added,
 o.date_modified,
 o.telephone,
 o.shipping_city,
 o.order_type,
 o.shipping_address_1 
FROM
 order o 
HAVING
 product_name LIKE '%smart tv3%'`
```

thanks to @wayneOS and other for responding my question :)